# Rails - One Main Redirect Controller for all half finished routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have two main controllers for my app, `AdminController` and `ApplicationController`.

My proper routes are `/admin/merchant/1`, `admin/merchant/1/shop/1` (Nested 1 level deep only =P)

However, many users will conveniently type `site.url/admin` or `site.url/merchant` out of convenience.

Is it pragmatic to `match` a few routes to a method in my admin controller and route them based on user? i.e. `match "/admin" => "admin#route_me"`

```
 before_filter :require_login

  def route_me
    if current_user.role?(:merchant)
      redirect_to admin_merchant_path(current_user.merchant)
    elsif current_user.role? :customer
      redirect_to admin_customer_path(currrent_user.customer)
    end
  end
```

**Is there a good implementation out there to universally catch-all half entered routes and try to "complete" the path for them?**

E.g. if the user types in admin/merchant/shops (missing merchant ID), my smart route knows he's trying to access his shop page, checks his ID and fill it up for him if he has one.